# Не срабатывает state() в aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, state

Проблема: не срабатывает функция в state()
Устанавливаю ServicesList.last_notes_list.set() и дальше должна выполнится `async def last_notes_list(message: types.Message):`, но этого не происходит. С другими стейтами `day_list` и  `month_list` все впорядке.

```
class ServicesList(StatesGroup):
    get_var = State()
    day_list = State()
    month_list = State()
    last_notes = State()

async def services_list_start(message: types.Message):
    var_list = ['За день', 'За месяц', 'Недавние записи']
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2, resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True)
    keyboard.add(*var_list)
    await ServicesList.get_var.set()
    await message.answer('Выбери вариант с клавиатуры', reply_markup=keyboard)


async def get_var_list(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    var = message.text
    if var == 'За день':
        days = ['Сегодня', 'Вчера']
        keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True, one_time_keyboard=True)
        keyboard.add(*days)
        await ServicesList.day_list.set()
        await message.answer('Выбери вариант с клавиатуры.', reply_markup=keyboard)
    elif var == 'За месяц':
        await ServicesList.month_list.set()
        await message.answer('Впиши номер месяца')
    elif var == 'Недавние записи':
        await ServicesList.last_notes.set()
        await message.answer('Секунду')
        print(await state.get_state())


async def day_list(message: types.Message):
    res = get_services_for_day(
        day=message.text,
        id_employee=message.from_user.id
    )
    for row in res:
        await message.answer(
            f'Id: {row[0]}\n'
            f'Услуга: {row[1]}\n'
            f'Сумма на руки: {row[2]}\n'
            f'Скидка: {row[3]}'
        )


async def month_list(message: types.Message):
    res = get_services_for_month(
        num_month=int(message.text),
        id_employee=message.from_user.id
    )
    for row in res:
        await message.answer(
            f'Id: {row[0]}\n'
            f'Услуга: {row[1]}\n'
            f'Сумма на руки: {row[2]}\n'
            f'Скидка: {row[3]}'
        )


async def last_notes_list(message: types.Message):
    print("Стейт сработал")
    res = get_last_notes(id_employee=message.from_user.id)
    for row in res:
        await message.answer(
            f'Id: {row[0]}\n'
            f'Услуга: {row[1]}\n'
            f'Сумма на руки: {row[2]}\n'
            f'Скидка: {row[3]}'
        )


def register_services_list(dp: Dispatcher):
    dp.register_message_handler(services_list_start, commands='services_list', state='*')
    dp.register_message_handler(get_var_list, state=ServicesList.get_var)
    dp.register_message_handler(day_list, state=ServicesList.day_list)
    dp.register_message_handler(month_list, state=ServicesList.month_list)
    dp.register_message_handler(last_notes_list, state=ServicesList.last_notes)


async def main(dp):
    register_handlers_common(dp)
    register_handlers_services(dp)
    register_services_list(dp)
    register_money_counter(dp)
    await set_commands(bot)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    executor.start_polling(dp, on_startup=main, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: Не совсем, понял. У вас юзер нажимает недавние записи, вы ему отвечаете секунду и меняете стейт. Но сам то он на запустится. Чтоб он сработал юзер должен что-то написать, при том неважно что

Comment: Я нажимаю «Недавние записи» -> функция get_var_list  определяет что мы выбрали именно «Недавние записи» и включает state - last_notes -> хендлер ‘’’dp.register_message_handler(last_notes_list, state=ServicesList.last_notes)’’’ должен вызвать функцию last_note_list(), которая и собирает и выводит эти записи, но функция не срабатывает

Comment: Этот хендлер last_notes_list срабатывает только если юзер что-то напишет боту

Comment: Так работают хендлеры. Из-за того что вы поменяли стейт ничего просто так не произойдет. Вы либо впихните код из хендлера под условие `var == ...`  либо меняйте логику бота

Comment: @oleksandrigo Понял, если можете, дайте совет, нормально выглядит такая конструкция или можно как то элегантнее сделать? Мб вообще не через стейты, а колбэки?

Comment: Ну инлайн кнопки более удобны, по моему мнению, и можно будет отказаться от стейтов. Ещё я бы посоветовал избавиться от регистрации хендлеров, используйте декораторы, код читается значительно лучше.